# Would it be possible to run pyautogui on a virtual machine without using my physical keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, virtual-machine, virtualbox, pyautogui

I'm planning on running a pyautogui script on a virtual machine in order to automate something while I'm doing something else on my main OS, is this possible?
I haven't tried it out yet but as far as I know, when I run a pyautogui script on a virtual machine or whatever, it uses my mouse and keyboard, and I can't do anything else while the script is running. So, the question is if it would be possible to run a pyautogui script and still being able to use my keyboard/mouse functions with a "virtual keyboard" or whatever you would call it?

Comment: I'm think the virtual machine will detect the same mouse and keyboard that your main OS is using and you wont be able to split control. Plugging in a second mouse and keyboard may [work](https://superuser.com/questions/12284/dedicated-mouse-and-keyboard-for-a-virtual-machine-is-it-possible) if you can set it up so each OS has it's own separate set.

Answer (score 2):

You will want a to run pyautogui automations on a system that is only used for automation. The system works by emulating mouse and keyboard events. If you are moving the mouse or using the keyboard you will mess with the automation.

If your code is running in a VM it is possible to keep the host OS from sharing mouse and keyboard inputs with the VM. Then you should be able to continue using the host OS while scripts are running.